# Texto sin traducción en el perfil

Tags: discusión, traducciones, perfil

Al ver el perfil de un usuario cualquiera que no tiene respuestas a ninguna pregunta se ve el texto sin traducir "answered" y debería cambiarse a "respondido":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En todo caso debería quedar:

> Este usuario no ha **respondido** ninguna pregunta.

También ocurre lo mismo cuando se observa las preguntas del usuario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque en este caso creo que se debería cambiar a algo que tenga más sentido ya que:

> Este usuario no tiene **preguntas** ninguna pregunta.

Es incorrecto, de acuerdo a los enlaces a los que apunta cada uno lo ideal sería:

> Este usuario no ha **preguntado** ninguna pregunta.

Y este último suena como al Chavo del 8. Creo que podría quedar así:

> Este usuario no ha **preguntado** aún.

¿Qué opinan?

**Actualización**

El perfil que he visitado para la parte de las preguntas es el de [Andres Vilca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/1792/andres-vilca)

Comment: ¿César puedes poner el link con un ejemplo? A mi me aparece como: "Este usuario no respondió ninguna pregunta": http://i.stack.imgur.com/gnTwP.png

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz me parece muy raro, en todo caso he puesto el enlace a uno de los perfiles del que me aparece el texto en inglés

Comment: Ok ya encontré, no era el tab Actividad sino en el tab Perfil, efectivamente sale en inglés

Comment: Ya encotré las cadenas en Transifex, ya corregí los errores y se los mandé a Juan para que los revise. A penas esté desplegado te aviso

Comment: Gracias @CarlosMuñoz :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

¡Ya está solucionado!

[image: Este usuario no ha respondido ninguna pregunta]

Comment: Perfecto, gracias Carlos, tengo que aprender a hacerlo yo mismo.

Comment: Pídele a Juan acceso a Transifex y lo podrás hacer tu mismo y apoyar en traducciones de futuras funcionalidades